# TypeORM update with join table (One-To-Many, Many-To-One)

Tags: mysql, typescript, orm, nestjs, typeorm

There are two example entities.

```js
@Entity('companies')
export class Company {
  @PrimaryColumn({ name: 'id' })
  id: string;

  @Column({ name: 'name' })
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => employee, (employee) => employee.company)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'id', referencedColumnName: 'company_id' })
  employees: Employee[];
}
```

```js
@Entity('employees')
export class Employee {
  @PrimaryColumn({ name: 'id' })
  id: string;

  @Column({ name: 'name' })
  name: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => company, (employee) => company.employees, { eagar: true, cascade: true} )
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'company_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  company: Company;
}
```

And I prepared the entity as follows for the update. (It can update my company's information or my employees' information.)

```js
const employee = new Employee();
employee.id = 'employee1';
employee.name = 'mike';

const companyEntity = await companyRepository.findByEmployeeId(employee_id);
companyEntity.name = 'stackoverflow';
companyEntity.employees = [employee];

await companyRepository.save(companyEntity);
```

If save like this, an error occurs because TypeORM processes as follows. (It wasn't an exact error. It was a similar error.)

```sh
// (Before the update, All users with 'company1' company have been inquired.)
query: SELECT employee.id FROM employee WHERE employee.company_id = 'company1'
query: UPDATE employee SET company_id = NULL WHERE employee.id = 'employee2'
query: UPDATE employee SET company_id = NULL WHERE employee.id = 'employee3'
query failed: Column 'company_id' cannot be NULL
```

In the end, it seems to be an error caused by all users belonging to the company trying to be inquired and updated.

What should I do to update the employees using the save method?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `employee.entitiy` file, I think you may have the relationship not quite right:

```
// company.entity.ts

@Entity('companies')
export class Company {
  @PrimaryColumn({ name: 'id' })
  id: string;

  @Column({ name: 'name' })
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Employee, (employee) => employee.company)
  employees: Employee[];
}
```

```
// employee.entity.ts

@Entity('employees')
export class Employee {
  @PrimaryColumn({ name: 'id' })
  id: string;

  @Column({ name: 'name' })
  name: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Company, (company) => company.employees)
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'company_id',
  })
  company: Company;
}
```

Personally, when updating a record, I'll do something like this—using your `employee` as an example:

```
// employee.service.ts

async updateEmployee(
    employeeId: string,
    updateEmployeeDto: UpdateEmployeeDto,
  ): Promise<Employee> {

    /**
    * This will stop the show and return a 404 if the employee cannot be found.
    */
    const employee = await this.getEmployeeById(employeeId); 

    const { name } = updateEmployeeDto;

    employee.name = name;

    try {
      await employee.save();
    } catch (err) {
      throw new InternalServerErrorException(err.message);
    }

    return employee;
  }
```

Or, if I am doing a `create` it might look something like this:

```
// employee.service.ts

async createEmployee(createEmployeeDto: CreateEmployeeDto): Promise<Employee> {
    return await this.employeeRepository.createEmployee(createEmployeeDto);
}
```

```
// employee.repository.ts

async createUser(createEmployeeDto: CreateEmployeeDto): Promise<Employee> {
    const { name } = createEmployeeDto;

    const employee = this.create();

    employee.name = name;

    try {
      await employee.save();
    } catch (err) {
      throw new InternalServerErrorException(err.message);
    }

    return employee;
  }
```